# CollapsingToolbarLayout title overlaps MenuIcons (it doesn't truncate)

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a problem with long titles in CollapsingToolbarLayout. It looks like this (on the right there is phone and overflow icons):

[image: Long title overlaping menu icons]

Code for this (and yes, I know that FAB is wrongly placed, but I keep it just for debug purposes - don't mind it please). I just want title to end (truncate) where icons start):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="265dp"
    android:background="?colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/placer" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:contentInsetStart="40dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: did you find any solution?